# Let $A$ be positive definite. Is $x'Ax\geq c \left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, positive-definite

The title is basically the whole question. Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix. Is it true that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $x'Ax \geq c \left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{2}$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if it's a matrix (finite-dimensional) and positive definite (not just positive semidefinite), there exists such a constant. The optimal one happens to be the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

Reference: [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to have a proof or a reference for the result?

Comment: I've added a reference to my answer. The proof isn't difficult, but boring. ;)

Comment: Thanks. The proof seems to be here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Answer (score 4):

An other way to approach it is the following:

When $A$ is positive difinite $x^tAx$ defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. On this space all norms are equivalent, and if I choose the standard one I get precisely the statement you where looking for.

If you look at the proof of equivalence of norms, you also get the best constant.

Comment: Just as a note: the proof of this general fact in this special case looks like this: Let c be the infimum of $ x^t A x $ for all unit vectors of x. Then c is greater than zero because the infimum is actually attained on the compact unit sphere. Furthermore the claimed inequality holds for any vector as is shown by dividing by $\|x\|^2$